# why does glutMouseFunc track state but glutKeyboardFunc does not?

Tags: glut, freeglut

I am working on a game using OpenGL and I noticed that I have to register a

`glutMouseFunc(void (*func)(int button, int state, int x, int y))`

to detect mouse presses and releases, but I have to register a

`glutKeyboardFunc(void (*func)(unsigned char button, int x, int y))`
and a

`glutKeyboardUpFunc(void (*func)(unsigned char button, int x, int y))`
(both of which I pipe to the function 
   `handleKey(char state unsigned char button, int x, int y)` 
function anyway)
to do the same thing for key presses.  Why doesn't glutKeyboardFunc just pass the state like glutMouseFunc does?

Comment: An average mouse has 3-5 buttons (left,right, middle, and maybe some thumb buttons). You can therefore encode the state of the mouse buttons in a single 8-bit bitmask. An average keyboard has 100+. You would thus need at least 100 bits to keep the entire state, 90% of which would be zeroes.

Comment: State is the state of the button passed, which brings up another question... why is mouse button an int but keyboard is a char